# Very strange AH00035 error

Tags: httpd, sftp, file-permissions

I am here because I have a very strange behaviour on my server and I ever investigate for hours on the  AH00035 error.

On my server, if I create a simple php file *index.php*

```
<? php echo "Hello world" ?>
```

I can reach it.

When I use the exact same file uploaded by sftp, I get the AH00035 error.
But when I copy the file, and apply the exact same permissions and user group than before, I don't have the error anymore.

Here is the scenario :

1 - Upload of the files using sftp

2 - Check the permissions of the file

```
-rw-r--r--.  1 SFTP_JOR_USER sftp_users index.php
```

3 - Mooving the file to my html directory

4 - Trying to access to the file : AH00035

5 - Changing users

```
 chown apache:apache index.php
```

6 - Trying to access the file : AH00035

HERE THE STRANGE PART

7 - Copying the file

```
cp index.php index2.php
```

8 - checking permission

```
-rw-r--r--.  1 root   root index2.php
```

9 - Accessing index2.php : *Hello world* (NICE !)

10 - Trying to make index.php on root

```
chown root:root index.php
```

11 - Trying to access index.php : AH00035

12 - Changing index.php and index2.php users

```
chown apache:apache index.php
chown apache:apache index2.php
```

So, finally, I have the EXACT SAME FILE, with EXACT SAME CONTENT and EXACT SAME PERMISSION.

One cause an AH00035 error.
The other one is accessible.

I really don't understand what happens here. Is it because of uploading them by sftp ???

I really don't want to make a copy of my files, then rename them, then change user group every time I make a change on my development.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *moved* the original file from your home directory to the web directory instead of *copying* it, thus the SELinux context of the file is wrong. When you move a file, its SELinux context is preserved by default.

You can resolve this in any of these ways:

1. *Copy* the file from your home directory to the web directory (then delete the original if desired). The new file will have the different SELinux context.
2. Move the file with `mv -Z` to reset the SELinux context to the default for the destination.
3. Upload the file with SFTP directly to its destination directory instead of your home directory.

Comment: God, it was working before and I used the cp command, I wanted to use the mv command to prevent me to delete the files from the SFTP upload folder...
Very instructive, thank you for your fast answer ! Genius !